# Avoid thirdparties conflicts of the same lib in C++

Tags: c++, cmake

Simplifying my current problem but here's the idea.

I have two thirdparties, include folders look like this:

```
lib_logging/include/lib_logging/lib_logging.h  # version 2.0

lib_cluster/include/lib_cluster/lib_cluster.h
lib_cluster/include/lib_logging/lib_logging_for_cluster.h  <- custom made header by lib_cluster
lib_cluster/include/lib_logging/lib_logging.h  # version 1.0
```

There's two different lib_logging.h, they're from the same library but they don't have the same version: different methods signatures and different macros. I know lib_logging.h should not be exposed since it is not useful for using lib_cluster, but I'm not the one making lib_cluster, modifying it correctly would take months and I can't wait months.

My main program must link on both libs: I want to use lib_logging 2.0 and lib_cluster. How can I do that? I can't just remove the `lib_cluster/include/lib_logging/` from the include dirs since lib_cluster may need it. Is there a way to tell the linker that a specific include dir is only for this 3rd party internally?

I'm using CMake, Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: are you linking static libraries? If so that limits your options, duplicate symbols will be removed. One solution would be to change the namespace of one of the files

Comment: Yes I'm static linking. How can I change the namespace of one of the files? (let's say lib_logging.h version 2.0)

Comment: please provide a [mre], you change the namespace with a text editor

Comment: The linker does not access the header files. That's what the compiler does. You may get away with modifying the order of the include directories, but this requires none of the symbols of `lib_logging` to be visible in `lib_cluster`...